# How to convert dotx file to html file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypandoc

This is my code which failing at the moment

```
import os
import pypandoc
source_dir = 'source'
result_dir = 'result'

for file in os.listdir(source_dir):

    output_files1 = []
    source_file = source_dir + '/'+file
    output_file = result_dir + '/'+file.replace('.dotx','.html').replace('.ott','.html')
    output = pypandoc.convert_file(source_file, 'html', outputfile=output_file)
```

I am trying to covert dotx file to html file, but I am getting the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Invalid input format! Got "dotx" but expected one of
these: commonmark, creole, docbook, docx, epub, fb2, gfm, haddock, 
html, jats, json, latex, markdown, markdown_github, markdown_mmd,
markdown_phpextra, markdown_strict, mediawiki, muse, native, odt, opml,
org, rst, t2t, textile, tikiwiki, twiki, vimwiki
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Pandoc supports `.docx`, unfortunately it doesn't look like Pandoc currently supports `.dotx` files in their [list of supported formats](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc)

Fortunately, since `.docx` and `.dotx` are nearly identical, you can simply change the file extension to `.docx` and Pandoc will be able to support it. See this question for more context: https://superuser.com/questions/1285415/difference-between-documents-with-docx-and-dotx-filename-extensions

Here's a bit of logic added into your existing loop to help rename any `.dotx` to `.docx` files:

```
import os
import pypandoc
source_dir = 'source'
result_dir = 'result'

for file in os.listdir(source_dir):
    if file.endswith('.dotx'):
        filename = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
        os.rename(file, filename + '.docx')
        file = filename + '.dotx'
    output_files1 = []
    source_file = source_dir + '/'+file
    output_file = result_dir + '/'+file.replace('.dotx','.html').replace('.ott','.html')
    output = pypandoc.convert_file(source_file, 'html', outputfile=output_file)
```

Hope this helps! Please let me know if you have any questions.